# Oracle - exporting xlsx - identifier 'as_xlsx' must be declared package

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have to generate a .xlsx file. I am following the instructions on this page: https://technology.amis.nl/2011/02/19/create-an-excel-file-with-plsql/

As said in the tutorial, I run this script to create the `as_xlsx` package: https://technology.amis.nl/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/as_xlsx18.txt

I need that this script work:

```
begin
    as_xlsx.query2sheet( 'SELECT column FROM table');
    as_xlsx.save( '/folder', 'my.xlsx');
end;
```

but don't work, with the following error: `PLS-00201: identifier 'AS_XLSX.QUERY2SHEET' must be declared`

I saw, that in the package created, showing the same message:
[image: error image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you created a package **body** without its specification.

```
SQL> create or replace package body pkg_test as
  2    procedure p_test is begin null; end;
  3  end;
  4  /

Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for PACKAGE BODY PKG_TEST:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
0/0      PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
1/14     PLS-00201: identifier 'PKG_TEST' must be declared
1/14     PLS-00304: cannot compile body of 'PKG_TEST' without its
         specification

SQL>
```

---

So: spec first, body next:

```
SQL> create or replace package pkg_test as
  2    procedure p_test;
  3  end;
  4  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body pkg_test as
  2    procedure p_test is begin null; end;
  3  end;
  4  /

Package body created.

SQL>
```

---

Maybe it is worth to mention:

- you can't have a package body without its specification, but
- you can have a package specification without the body

  - what would be its purpose? To declare types and constants that will be used throughout the application